# Git : Pulled repository in wrong directory

Tags: github, tortoisegit

I have pulled git repository form github in my user folder and all files copied there.
I have also installed tortoise git on my system so all other files in that directory (contacts , my pictures etc..) shows version symbol on that.

How can i undo these or remove that files from tortoise Git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea of tortoise git, but most likely removing `.git` directory from the root of the checkout should make it forget about versioning.